# Sum a column based on another column and append that column in dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to sum the values in count column based on place column and after that append values in sum column.

Output so far:

```
         lat       lon       place  predict  count
0  51.375339 -0.390005      London        0     15
1  53.362981 -2.929597   Liverpool        0      2
2  51.375339 -0.390005      London        1      2
3  53.426872 -2.280006  Manchester        0      1
```

Desired Output:

```
         lat       lon       place  predict  count  Sum
0  51.375339 -0.390005      London        0     15   17
1  53.362981 -2.929597   Liverpool        0      2    2
2  51.375339 -0.390005      London        1      2   17
3  53.426872 -2.280006  Manchester        0      1    1
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to use the pandas [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) function. This would give you the total sum for each place. You can then merge those results back into the original dataframe to get your desired output.

```
sums = df.groupby('place').sum()['count']
sums = sums.rename('sum')
df.merge(sums, on='place')
```